# Allow users to customize feed on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hot-questions

The feed section is nice because of all the new things going on in your accounts like comments, privileges coming up, notifications etc.

But I think some items are bugging me more than they are a "nice add-on".

I would be a very nice addition for users to be able to filter what is in that section. Like :

> - Hot Questions ☐
> - Notifications   ☑
> - Job Offers      ☐
> - ...